# Python: range operation with list

Tags: python, list, range

I have list of elements like this: `[1/1/9-1/1/13, 1/1/20-1/1/22]`

and I would like to print the numbers in the range between 9 and 13, 20 and 22

```
Result= [1/1/10, 1/1/11, 1/1/12, 1/1/21 ]
```

The range() method could do this, but how to catch them?

Comment: Those are supposed to be strings right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>test = ['1/1/9-1/1/13', '1/1/20-1/1/22']
>>>test = [tuple(x.split('-')) for x in test]
>>>print test
[('1/1/9', '1/1/13'), ('1/1/20', '1/1/22')]
>>>result = [x[:x.rfind('/')+1]+str(t) for x,y in test for t in range(int(x.split('/')[-1])+1, int(y.split('/')[-1]))]
>>>print result
['1/1/10', '1/1/11', '1/1/12', '1/1/21']
```

I guess this is you want.

Comment: Excellent :) i'm new to python and this is what i was loking for  have you succeed when executing the "result" line? I got this error message "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1/1/9'"

Comment: @user1435173 sorry, i made a mistake. Now it is right.